# Systematically Remove an Internet Connection

Tags: networking, vpn, fortinet, dialup

We are about to deploy FortiNet FortiClient VPN to our end users however we're running into one small snag. During the installation it also creates a dial-up connection which appears in the WiFi pup-up menu (Everyone is Windows 10). Our current VPN connection is also setup in that same location so we don;t want our users attempting to use the dial-up connection instead of the actual FortiClient app.

Does anyone know how to systematically remove this? I have tried netsh, PowerShell NetAdapter commands and WMI commands, registry editing, and a few other random commands i came across but nothing is working.

The connection can be found in the WiFi pop-up

[image: WiFi pop-up],

the connections tab in internet options

[image: connections tab in internet options],

and is an actual network connection in the network connections console

[image: network connection in the network connections console].

I have removed any company specific information so if you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: bump.still pulling my hair out over this. enabling/disabling the WMI object does nothing and since it's considered a read-only property. I feel like this should be  a simple task and i'm just overlooking something.

Answer (score 1):

Alright i spent way too much time on this but i figured it out. All i had to do was modify the **rasphone.pbk** file in **C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk**

I found zero documentation on this and it seems like Microsoft just never went back and updated this process. It seems to be left over legacy stuff that has just fallen by the wayside. If you create a new dial-up or VPN connection it will populate this file (C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk_hiddenPbk\rasphone.pbk) with all of the properties. You can then go back and edit it accordingly.

**Note:** I used the **All Users** folder to change this so that it overwrites whatever is currently configured. If you want to do this on a per user basis be sure to remove this file completely from the ALL Users because it always takes presidence over individual user config.